# Removing previous activity from current activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a stack of activities like A->B->C->D... Back function is enabled on all activities. Now on a specific action on activity D, I would like to move to activity B i.e. D&C gets finished now and activity B is resumed. How to achieve such transition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to follow proper and ideal flow , go for "onActivityResult" method. Suppose for your example when B goes to C, at that time it will start activity C using startActivityForResult and when C goes to D then again C will use statActivityForResult to go do D.

For your case,

```
public class B extends Activity
{
   public static int RESULT_CODE=111;

   public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance)
   {
   ...
   ....
   Intent intent = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
   }


   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if(requestcode == C.RESULT_OK)
       {

       //do you work when D is finished and comes back to B
        }

    }


public class C extends Activity
{
     public static int RESULT_CODE=222;

     public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance)
     {
     ...
     ....
     Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,D.class);
     startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
     }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestcode == D.RESULT_OK)
    {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }

   } 


    public class D extends Activity
    {
      public static int RESULT_CODE=333;

      public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance)
      {
      ...
      ....

      }


      //your back click function

      public void onBackClick(View v)
      {
      setResult(RESULT_OK);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mrugesh. This particular solution solved the above problem in most suitable way and I guess this should be the most preferred way to perform an action on previous activity in response to the action from a next activity.

Answer (score 1):

From Activity D, call Activity B with proper flags in the Intent. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should do it.

Example code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: `Intent Intent=new Intent(this,B.class);
 Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  );
 Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(Intent);`

            finish();

I did this.. but first Activity A flashes up and than Activity B is shown.. just like i could peep through the stack until my activity loads

Comment: Try it without the finish() call.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code inside some action of `D` Activity

```
 C close = new C();
 close.finish();
 D.this.finish();
```

And in activity tag of manifest file add this attribute

```
android:launchmode="singleTop" //Or singleTask
```

So that you can close both c and D activity and resume into B.

Comment: Thanks tilak. but wouldn't that create a new instance of activity C and kill that one.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, use this API < 11:

```
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, Login2.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(Intent);
```

In API level 11 a new Intent Flag was added just for this: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

```
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, Login2.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(Intent);
```